# Baryon / lepton number violation equivalence in Sakharov conditions

Tags: cosmology, conservation-laws, beyond-the-standard-model, cp-violation, baryogenesis

In the Sakharov conditions for matter-antimatter asymmetry the [requirement for the baryon number violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryogenesis#Sakharov_conditions) is often [interchanged with lepton number violation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/6322/116294). In the context of the Sakharov conditions, how is it that baryon number violation can be equivalent to lepton number violation?

Comment: The reason is that one often assumes Baryogenesis via Leptogenesis . Have a look at the answeres here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158943/baryogenesis-via-leptogenesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Standard Model, the baryon and lepton number are accidental global symmetries. However, they are conserved only at the classical level: quantum corrections do not respect them, i.e., they are *anomalous*.

The interesting thing is that they are violated by exactly the same amount. In terms of currents we write:

$$\partial_\mu J_B^\mu=\partial_\mu J_L^\mu \neq 0$$

From here you see that the current $B-L$ is conserved (anomaly-free) but not $B+L$.

Therefore any violation of baryon number leads in principle to a violation of lepton number by the same amount (to keep $B-L$ conserved), and vice versa. This is mediated by the so-called *sphalerons*. However, sphaleron transition are extremely suppressed at energies below the electroweak scale so baryogenesis via leptogenesis scenarios must go to higher scales.